# How to make apps from MS app reg portal show up in my Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Im trying to start working with the v2.0 endpoint, I registered my web app in the new Application registration portal, but I cannot find it anywhere in my Azure AD. Should I not be able to see it there?

I tried creating an app both with my work azure account, and with an account I created specifically in the tenant. Neither works. Am I missing something?a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find it `Azure Active Directory`-->`Enterprise applications`-->`All applications`.

[image]

But you only could see Azure AD only applications. Currently, Converged applications could not see on Azure Portal, please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/18911212-where-is-application-registered-in-azure-active-di).

Update from comment:

The blade enterprise applications represents service principals in the AAD tenant, not applications. Once you sign into the app & consent or manually provision a service principal, you'll see it in this list.

Comment: That is where I have been looking

Comment: If you select `All applications` could you see your app?

Comment: no, it does not show up. I am looking in the correct tenant, with the correct user, and created the app using the correct user in the app reg portal.

Comment: You are your AD Global Administrator? It needs Global administrator permission.

Comment: Yes I am global admin

Comment: Hi, when you select, select `All applications`, status `Any`. You are your directory global administrator not your subscription admin role.

Comment: yes, I am signed in with 'Admin@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com' , the same user that I created the app with. And it is a global admin. Have I missed something during the app registration process? I just added a web app with a name, and a redirect URL. Nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159135/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-green-qaue).

Comment: @Green_qaue The blade `enterprise applications` represents service principals in the AAD tenant, not applications. Once you sign into the app & consent or manually provision a service principal, you'll see it in this list.

Comment: @DanielDobalian Thanks for your reply, I will update my answer.